# Initialize array of structures

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, struct, initialization

I am having trouble initializing an array of structures in C.
Here is my structure :

```
typedef struct Voie {
    int num;
    int sem_num[3];
    int crois[3];
} Voie;
```

The two arrays will contain 0, 2 or 3 integers.

I have an array of 12 "Voie" :

```
Voie voies[12];
```

And I want each of these to be initialized with these parameters :

```
{1,{0,16,1},{4,7,8}}
{2,{2,3},{4,5}}
{3,{},{}}
{4,{4,17,5},{7,10,11}}
{5,{6,7},{7,8}}
{6,{},{}}
{7,{8,17,9},{10,1,2}}
{8,{10,11},{10,11}}
{9,{},{}}
{10,{12,16,13},{1,4,5}}
{11,{14,15},{1,2}}
{12,{},{}}
```

I have tried with a function returning a structure, separating each case with a switch, but got redefinition issues.
Then I found what I assume to be the best solution but still can't make it run :

```
int cas[][] = { {1,{0,16,1},{4,7,8}},
                    {2,{2,3},{4,5}},
                    {3,{},{}},
                    {4,{4,17,5},{7,10,11}},
                    {5,{6,7},{7,8}},
                    {6,{},{}},
                    {7,{8,17,9},{10,1,2}},
                    {8,{10,11},{10,11}},
                    {9,{},{}},
                    {10,{12,16,13},{1,4,5}},
                    {11,{14,15},{1,2}},
                    {12,{},{}}  };

for (i=0 ; i<12 ; i++) {
    voies[i] = cas[i];
}
```

I'm not even sure that this is possible, since the following works :

```
Voie v = {1,{0,16,1},{4,7,8}};
```

But not the following :

```
int tab[] = {1,{0,16,1},{4,7,8}};
Voie v = tab;
```

Also : how can I access to each of the elements in my structure once it is initialized ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What led you to this: `int cas[][]`?

Comment: This was the solution given on another post. The problem was almost the same as mine.

Comment: So many duplicates I do not know which one to use for closing this.

Comment: So you might like to link this answer?

Comment: Sorry, I just understand what you meant. The answer I'm talking about didn't say int cas[][] but int cas[][9] but since I didn't know what the size was in my case, I let it empty. http://stackoverflow.com/a/22927133/4403802

Comment: `int cases[][9]` is not the same as `int cas[][]`. You are only allowed to remove the leftmost number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply initialize your array with:

EDITED:

```
Voie voies[12] = { 
                {1,{0,16,1},{4,7,8}},
                {2,{2,3,},{4,5,}},
                {3,{0,},{0,}},
                {4,{4,17,5},{7,10,11}},
                {5,{6,7,},{7,8,}},
                {6,{0,},{0,}},
                {7,{8,17,9},{10,1,2}},
                {8,{10,11,},{10,11,}},
                {9,{0,},{0,}},
                {10,{12,16,13},{1,4,5}},
                {11,{14,15,},{1,2,}},
                {12,{0,},{0,}}  
};
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that all members/elements not being initialised explicitly in this case get initialised to `0` implicitly.

Comment: It is also worth mentioning that this is not standard C. Empty `{}` are not allowed. (They are for C++)

Comment: Which makes this answer simply wrong. There are enough C compilers out there that will flat out reject this as a syntax error. (Even if it's wrong in the question as well, it should be mentioned.)

Comment: Thanks for editing, it looks good (to me, anyway) now. One thing that might be worth covering as well is what @alk hints at too: instead of `{3,{0,},{0,}},`, you can simply write `{3},` or `{3,},`. But if you prefer it the way you have it now, that's fine too.

Comment: Basically I want to do something for each element of the arrays. So currently I'm using a for loop, from 0 to 2, but if the array is empty, I don't want to do anything, and if it only contains 2 elements, I want to do something only 2 times. So I'm initializing the arrays with 3 elements anyway, which leads to some `{-1,-1,-1}`and `{1,2,-1}` and I test the value in the for loop and do stuff only if it's different from -1. What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

You can access the elements like voies[5].sem_num[0].

If Im not wrong, the example value above would be 17.

Comment: In the original example, `voies[5].sem_num[0]` is zero. You probably ment `voies[6].sem_num[1]` which is 17.

Comment: Exactly, Marian. I was just trying to see if everyone was paying attention... :P
(JK, my mistake! Thanks for pointing out it!)

@Scentle5S, just dont do like me did, ok?

Answer (score 2):

Neither your declaration `cas[][]` nor your initialization with empty `{}` is standard C.

You may have at most one empty `[]` in a declaration, and you'd have to put at least one `0` inside the `{}`.